# transpose column into rows through delimiter

Tags: text, notepad++, transpose, textpad

I have data in the following format. The values are in one column. I need to transpose them keeping the delimiter. I tried replacing the values using regular expression '\r\n' but it does nothing.

```
653
|110
|1 January 2016
|Default
|Automatically identified, customer dialed
|None
|NPA dialed by customer
|000-380-5414
|03:59:57.5
|4:01.9
|CIC = 0000 |1 January 2016
|03:59:35.5
|4:23.9
|10
|SS7 from IC to AT, SS7 to EO |Tandem
|104
|Routing Indicator = Direct - Incoming Different network |104
|Routing Indicator = Direct - Outgoing Different network |119
|Trunk Group Number - Interoffice = 9056 |Network Interface Description = Feature Group D
|Administrative Domain = 0 |Final module
|
625
|119
|1 January 2016
|Default
|Automatically identified, customer dialed
|None
|000-000-0000
|NPA dialed by customer
|000-380-5084
|04:04:26.6
|0:00.0
|CIC = 0000 |1 January 2016
|04:04:24.6
|0:01.9
|01
|SS7 from IC to AT, SS7 to EO |Tandem
|CAC not dialed, station not presub, no presub ind
|Neither ANI nor CPN provided
|104
|Routing Indicator = Direct - Incoming Different network |104
|Routing Indicator = Direct - Outgoing Different network |119
|Trunk Group Number - Interoffice = 9056 |Network Interface Description = Feature Group D
|Administrative Domain = 0 |Final module
|
```

How do i convert this to the following structure

```
653|110|1 January 2016|Default|...
652|119|1 January 2016|Default|...
```

I have textpad and notepad++. Any assistance is much appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

Find what: `\r\n\|`
Replace with: `\|`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R\|`
- Replace with: `|`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R  : any kind of line break
\|  : pipe character
```